# java.awt.Desktop.open doesn’t work with PDF files?

Tags: java, desktop

It looks like I cannot use Desktop.open() on PDF files regardless of location. Here's a small test program:

```
package com.example.bugs;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DesktopOpenBug {
    static public void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Desktop desktop = null;
            // Before more Desktop API is used, first check 
            // whether the API is supported by this particular 
            // virtual machine (VM) on this particular host.
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                for (String path : args)
                {
                    File file = new File(path);
                    System.out.println("Opening "+file);
                    desktop.open(file);
                }
            }           
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I run DesktopOpenBug with arguments `c:\tmp\zz1.txt c:\tmp\zz.xml c:\tmp\ss.pdf` (3 files I happen to have lying around) I get this result: (the .txt and .xml files open up fine)

```
Opening c:\tmp\zz1.txt
Opening c:\tmp\zz.xml
Opening c:\tmp\ss.pdf
java.io.IOException: Failed to open file:/c:/tmp/ss.pdf. Error message:
    The parameter is incorrect.

at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.open(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Desktop.open(Unknown Source)
at com.example.bugs.DesktopOpenBug.main(DesktopOpenBug.java:21)
```

What the heck is going on? I'm running WinXP, I can type "c:\tmp\ss.pdf" at the command prompt and it opens up just fine.

**edit:** if this is an example of [Sun Java bug #6764271](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6764271) please help by voting for it. What a pain. >:(

Comment: You should really edit your original question rather than create a new one.

Comment: There would be enough of an edit that I decided to vote to close my original question + open a new one. This one has nothing to do with UNC paths and the only answer I got had to do with UNC paths and spaces.

Comment: In fact, even better: I've deleted the old question as it has no value at this point.

Answer (score 8):

I never knew about this Desktop command, untill recently through this post:
[would Java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec() run on windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571604/would-javas-runtime-getruntime-exec-run-on-windows-7)

Previously i have been using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL "+ myfile);
```

And it has always worked for me. If your method does not work, may be you can think about try this command.

Comment: it helps but only on Windows. (I use both MacOS and Windows.)

Answer (score 2):

<s>If you switch the order of your arugments does that cause one of the other files to get that same error.  I wonder if you need to trim the end of the path before calling the File constructor.</s>

umm...yeah ignore that... check [the documentation of `Desktop.open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29). `open` throws an IO exception "if the specified file has no associated application or the associated application fails to be launched " ... also from the top of the page... "The mechanism of registereing, accessing, and launching the associated application is platform-dependent. "

---

code for the Desktop class: http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/awt/Desktop-source.html

The open method calls `DesktopPeer.open`.

DesktopPeer source: http://www.jdocs.com/javase/7.b12/java/awt/peer/DesktopPeer.html

DesktopPeer is implementation specific.

Here is source for a Windows-specific implementation:
http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Platform/windows/sun/awt/windows/WDesktopPeer.java.htm

`open->ShellExecute->(Native)ShellExecute`

Native `ShellExecute` is a wrapper for Win32 `ShellExecute`.  Here is info on the function.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx

My suggestion for a work around would be to write your own implmentation of the ShellExecute function.  Here is source from someone who did it.  http://www.heimetli.ch/shellexec.html

Comment: umm...yeah ignore that... check this link http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File) ...open throws a IO exception "if the specified file has no associated application or the associated application fails to be launched " ... also from the top of the page... "The mechanism of registereing, accessing, and launching the associated application is platform-dependent. "

Comment: PDF files have an associated application on my machine and I have no idea how to debug what is going on. All it says is "The parameter is incorrect" which sounds like a Microsoft COM/ActiveX bug.