# would Java's Runtime.getRuntime().exec() run on windows 7?

Tags: java, windows, windows-7

i have windows xp and developing some java swing application.
In my program i am using

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL "+ myfile);`

to open the file produced from my program in windows default editor.

It works fine on my system. I just want to know would it work OK on windows 7.
Are there any security aspects to this process execution in windows 7 which does not show up in windows XP?

Answer (score 9):

Not a direct answer, but you're supposed to use [`Desktop#open()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) for this to be platform independent.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

Comment: Ok, but would this work seamlessly or user would be prompted for any security issue. I don't see any in XP, i hope it would be the same in Windows 7

Comment: I can confirm that it works flawlessly on Win7 here as well. The standard Java API has already taken the nasty platform-specific details into account.

Comment: for URLs use the browse method 

java.net.URI uri = new java.net.URI("http://www.infocaptor.com" );
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(uri);