# How to open and view a file(similar to that of double clicking a file) using Java

Tags: java, file-io, platform-independent

I would like to know to know the code in Java that that will help perform the same operation as that of a double click in any OS on a file making it open and thereby enable us to view its contents when the user supplies the location of the file in his/her PC. Any suggestion would be of great help as i need it to finish my application.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487149/how-to-open-the-notepad-file-in-java) has the answers you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [Desktop.open(File)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29)

Comment: Note that the Desktop.open(File) method has some bugs.  See http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6631015 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527162/java-awt-desktop-open-doesnt-work-with-pdf-files, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code. On windows, you will get a windows file open dialog if no program is associated with the file type. If it does not run on windows, it falls back to `Desktop.open()`, which works if the file type is known to the system.

```
public static boolean openFile(File file){
  try {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows")) {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
          "rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
      Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  } catch (final Exception e1) {
    System.err.println("Error opening file " + file, e1);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in windows xp:

```
rundll32 shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL "file:///d:\download\theapp.lnk"
```

you could add registry so that you could run lnk file in RUN dialog box and folder cruiser:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shell\edit]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\lnkfile\shell\edit\command]
@="rundll32 shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL \"file:///%1\""
```