# Desktop.getDesktop().open(file) on Ubuntu not working

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, awt

I have a Java application, and when I use java.awt.Desktop:

```java
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

It works fine on Windows (opens a file in my default program), but on Ubuntu (with openJdk 13), the Java application gets stuck and I do not even get any log error or anything. I have to force quit the app in order to recover.

The file path it correct, otherwise I would actually get an Exception. Also, `isDesktopSupported` a `isSupported(Action.OPEN)` returns `true`.

What can I do? Can I check some system settings or logs? Or perhaps get some logs from `java.awt.Desktop`? Or does this not work on Ubuntu/Linux?

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open a path with Desktop.open() from java on ubuntu (linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692331/open-a-path-with-desktop-open-from-java-on-ubuntu-linux)

Comment: @DuncG it does not. The issue you linked is about path problems and they have clear exception. I do not get any exception, the program is just stuck.

Comment: Do you use JavaFX too? There have been issues in this area https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8195086

Comment: This is actually exactly whats happening, but it is resolved in JDK 8 it seems, but I am using open jdk 13 and I am experiencing this problem, which is weird then.

Comment: @DuncG okay I went through a relative issue to the one you linked and there one comment helped... posting that as an answer now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8096706?focusedCommentId=13785982&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13785982):

In order to use the API, you have to call java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater() and call methods of the Desktop class from a runnable passed to the invokeLater():

```
void fxEventHandler() {
   EQ.invokeLater(() -> {
      Desktop.open(...);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to add an example function

```
    private static void OpenFile(String filePath){
            try
            {
                //constructor of file class having file as argument
                File file = new File(filePath);
                if(!Desktop.isDesktopSupported())//check if Desktop is supported by Platform or not
                {
                    System.out.println("not supported");
                    return;
                }
                Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
                if(file.exists()) {         //checks file exists or not
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
                        try {
                            desktop.open(file);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```